# Why setRemoteDescription prevents execution flow?

Tags: flutter, udp, webrtc

I have this project where I am trying to chat with WebRTC without Internet, using UDP over LAN.
My code is based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAKQzNQmNe0

How works my code:

- The original code from video created a video chat using `firebase`. It worked!
- There are four main methods `OpenUserMedia`, `createRoom`, `joinRoom` and `hangUp`.
- Methods `OpenUserMedia` and `hangUp` are intact. So I hope they are flawless.
- Method `createRoom` manages caller side and `joinRoom` manages callee side.
- My changes are replacing `firebase` comunication to UDP communication.
- Method `sendMessage` sends data through UDP and `listenForMessage` receives whenever a message comes. The communication works.
- Method `createRoom` sends both messages with `ICECandidate` and with `Offer`.
- Method `joinRoom` does receive both messages with `ICECandidate` (callerCandidates) and with `Offer`.

```flutter
  Future<void> joinRoom(String roomId, RTCVideoRenderer remoteVideo) async {
    // print('Create PeerConnection with configuration: $configuration');
    peerConnection = await createPeerConnection(configuration);

    registerPeerConnectionListeners();

    localStream?.getTracks().forEach((track) {
      peerConnection?.addTrack(track, localStream!);
    });

    // Code for collecting ICE candidates below
    peerConnection!.onIceCandidate = (RTCIceCandidate? candidate) {
      if (candidate == null) {
        // print('onIceCandidate: complete!');
        return;
      }
      Communicating.sendMessage(
          {'type': 'calleeCandidates', 'data': candidate.toMap()});
      calleeCandidates.add(candidate.toMap());
      // addMyCandidate(candidate.toMap());
    };
    // Code for collecting ICE candidate above

    peerConnection?.onTrack = (RTCTrackEvent event) {
      // print('Got remote track: ${event.streams[0]}');
      event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) {
        // print('Add a track to the remoteStream: $track');
        remoteStream?.addTrack(track);
      });
    };

    Communicating.listenForMessage((responseMessage) async {
      var data = responseMessage['data'];
      // Code for creating SDP answer below
      if (responseMessage['type'] == 'offer') {
        // print('Got offer $data');
        var offer = data['offer'];
        await peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(
          RTCSessionDescription(offer['sdp'], offer['type']),
        );
        var answer = await peerConnection!.createAnswer();
        // print('Created Answer $answer');

        await peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(answer);

        Map<String, dynamic> roomWithAnswer = {
          'answer': {'type': answer.type, 'sdp': answer.sdp}
        };

        Communicating.sendMessage({'type': 'offer', 'data': roomWithAnswer});
        // Finished creating SDP answer
        // Listen for remote Ice candidates below
      } else if (responseMessage['type'] == 'callerCandidates') {
        peerConnection!.addCandidate(
          RTCIceCandidate(
            data['candidate'],
            data['sdpMid'],
            data['sdpMLineIndex'],
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

#### The problem:

My issue is when `joinRoom` method receives a message with offer type. It goes inside `if (responseMessage['type'] == 'offer') {` however it leaves after calling `setRemoteDescription` method. (code below is the same from above)

```flutter
await peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(
          RTCSessionDescription(offer['sdp'], offer['type']),
        );
```

That means it never calls `await peerConnection!.createAnswer();`.
It does not throw any Exception.

#### My question

Why does it never execute the last 3 commands from `if (responseMessage['type'] == 'offer')`? Am I missing something?

#### Additional information

This is a picture where I am debugging on that exact point.
[image: Debugging]

Comment: Is there an exception happening on the call to `setRemoteDescription`? I notice from your screenshot that "Uncaught Exceptions" is unmarked in your debugger and there's no `try`/`catch` or `onError` logic in the code you've shared. Dart/Flutter asynchronous code is notoriously bad about failing without any trace of an error having occured.

Comment: I have tried mark "Uncaught Exceptions" before, but nothing showed up. Anyway, I have tried `try`/`catch` now and it also didn't bring any clue.

Comment: You might try adding breakpoints to the individual lines within `setRemoteDescription`s implementation. I've had a time where an asynchronous method in dart trying to make a network connection threw an error that could not be caught by `try`/`catch` or any other method. Turned out that Dart just doesn't support handling some sorts of asynchronous exceptions. I unfortunately can't find the Github thread describing the issue at the moment.